# How to call React action creator inside Redux-Form Field component which is inside a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, semantic-ui-redux-form-fields

I am using `redux-form Field` component inside a parent component `ParentComponent`, where I am passing a `component={MyComponent}`. This `MyComponent` needs to get dynamically updated on `axios` call callbacks. I am getting the warning
`‘React does not recognize the myActionCreatorMethod prop on a DOM element’`. Can someone guide me on how to get the values properly in child component?

```js
ParentComponent {
  render() { <
    Field
    name = "someFieldName"
    type = "text"
    component = {
      MyComponent
    }
    />
  }
}

MyComponent {
  someMethod = () => {
    this.props.myActionCreatorMethod()
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    myActionCreatorMethod,
  }, dispatch)
}
```

Comment: The snippet you posted throws an error...

Comment: This is a pseudo code for understanding purpose.

Comment: This pseudo code does not help understanding the actual syntax you are using. Please post the full code otherwise it is hard to debug.